# Why doesn't child process continue running after receiving signal?

Tags: unix, process, fork, signals

The following is my code. Parent forks a child. Child pause until parent sends a signal to it, then it continues running. 
My question is why doesn't child process continue 
running after parent sending signal to him. Did I miss or misunderstand something?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<signal.h>


void 
sigusr1( int pidno )
{
  printf("Catched\n");
}

int 
main()
{
  pid_t pid;

  signal( SIGUSR1, sigusr1 );
  if( (pid = fork()) == 0 ){
    pause();
  printf("Child\n"); 
  }

  kill( pid , SIGUSR1 ); //parent sends signal to child 
  pause();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what happens in the parent:

1. Fork a child.
2. Send SIGUSR1 to the child.
3. Wait for a signal.

Here's what happens in the child:

1. Wait for a signal.
2. Print `Child`.
3. Call `kill(0, SIGUSR1)` (0 being the value of `pid` in the child). Calling `kill` with a process ID of 0 sends the signal to every process in the [process group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_group) of the process that calls `kill`.
4. Wait for a signal.

There are several possible behaviors for your program, depending on the order in which the parent and the child system calls are executed. Depending on the exact version of your operating system, on the fine-tuning of various kernel parameters, on how loaded your system is, and on random chance, you may or may not observe different behavior if you run the program several times or under a debugger.

If the parent starts faster than the child, you may see this:

1. Parent sends SIGUSR1 to the child.
2. Child receives SIGUSR1 and prints `Catched`.
3. Child calls `pause`.
4. Parent calls `pause`.

With this execution order, both the parent and the child end up waiting forever (it's a [deadlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock)).

If the child starts faster than the parent, you may see this:

1. Child calls `pause`.
2. Parent sends SIGUSR1 to the child.
3. Parent calls `pause`.
4. Child is unblocked and prints `Catched`.
5. Child prints `Child`.
6. Child sends SIGUSR1 to the process group.
7. Child prints `Catched`.
8. Child calls `pause`.
9. Parent is unblocked and prints `Catched`.
10. Parent exits.

I don't think there's a way for the child to exit: it calls `pause` twice, and while it can receive up to two signals, one of these is sent from itself (the one from `kill(0,SIGUSR1)`) and that one is delivered synchronously, not during the execution of `pause`.

This program is probably not what you meant to write, but since you don't describe the expected behavior, it's impossible to tell what you did mean to write. I do note that you do not follow the usual structure of a program that forks:

```
pid = fork();
if (pid < 0) {
    /*error handling*/
} else if (pid == 0) {
    /*child code*/
    exit(...); /*Usually, what follows the if is specific to the parent.*/
}
```

Comment: That "kill" (i.e. "send signal") was accidentally being called twice (once in the parent, and once in the child) was exactly what I tried to say in the first place.  Worse, the child was (again, inadvertantly) sending a "kill 0".  That was the main problem.  A secondary problem might have been the line buffering (affecting the order and time lines were displayed).

Comment: @paulsm4 When the output is to a terminal, stdout is line buffered or unbuffered; this is specified by [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_05.html) and more generally in C (see e.g. [N1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) §7.19.3.7).

Comment: Your quote: "stdout is line buffered or unbuffered".By default, on virtually all implementations (X terminal, putty window, text-mode frame buffer, etc etc) for virtually all *nix (including Linux) the stdio default is "buffered".   And exactly what does the C99 standard have to do with "terminal I/O"???

Comment: @14moose Stdio defaults to **line** buffering when the output is a terminal. On all C implementations. The C standard (I cited C99, but C89 has similar language) is relevant because this is a C program (and POSIX includes the C standard by reference).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<signal.h>


void
sigusr1( int pidno )
{
  fprintf(stderr, "Caught\n");
}

int
main()
{
  pid_t pid;

  signal( SIGINT, sigusr1 );
  if( (pid = fork()) == 0 ){
    pause();
    fprintf(stderr, "Child\n");
  }
  else
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Parent\n");
    kill( pid , SIGINT ); //parent sends signal to child
  }
  pause();
  return 0;
}
```

1. `printf` buffers input: perhaps it's being called, but it isn't being displayed when you expect.  One workaround is `fflush()`.  A better workaround is `fprintf (stderr)`, which doesn't buffer in the first place.
2. You're calling `kill()` in both the parent and the child.  I added an `else` to eliminate this.
3. Here's sample output:

```
gcc -Wall -g -o z z.c

./z
Parent
Caught
Child
```

Comment: Thank you. I copied your code but it seems that it does not work on my mac.

Comment: I think the reason is signal is sent before pause running.

Comment: #1 is wrong: if the program is printing on a terminal, it will use line buffering. #2 is right, but I think not the whole problem.

Comment: @Gilles - no: printing *is* buffered.  Buffering is Good in general, but it can produce unexpected results with multiple processes or multiple threads.  And yes, WHERE the kill was in the original code, WAS the main problem.

Comment: @Janus Le - "signal()" sets a signal handler.  "kill()" sends a signal to a process.  It's Good that signal was called before "fork()" and before the subsequent "pause()".

Comment: Also - the parent and child are not "deadlocked". They're just waiting on "pause()" - they are NOT waiting on each other!

Comment: this only printed parent caught